# How to get list of movies with their full details in omdbAPI

Tags: api, video, web-applications, request, frontend

I am developing a web application to allow users to search for movies using keyword. So I decided to use the omdbAPI to fetch movie data. However, the result does not contain full details of movie such as genre, date of release etc.

My question here is, how do I make my request to return a list of detailed movie objects?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the Fetch API you would do something like the following:

```js
fetch("http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=[yourkey]&t=[movietitle]")
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((data) => console.log(data))
```

The `response` object returned in the first `then` does not **directly** contain the actual JSON response body but it a representation of the entire HTTP response. In order to get the actual JSON response, you need to invoke the `json()` method on the response object. 
Now according to the OMBDb API documentation, if you want to get a list of movies you need to specificy the `s` parameter in the request and then access the `Search` attribute on the JSON response.

```js
fetch("http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=[yourkey]&s=Antman")
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((data) => console.log(data.Search))
```

This will print out:

```js
Array [ {…} ]
  0: Object { Title: "The Antman", Year: "2002", imdbID: "tt0321249", … }
  length: 1
```

If you want to retrieve a specific movie you can specify the `i` (id) or `t` (title) parameter:

```js
fetch("http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=[yourkey]&t=Antman")
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((data) => console.log(data))
```

In this case, you won't need to access the `Search` attribute and the `data` will contain the actual movie data.

Comment: Thanks so much @B0ttiX. My challenge here is that, the movie object in the result from the request made using "s" query parameter contains only five properties (Type, imdbID, Year, Poster and Title). How do I make it contain all properties?

Comment: Given how the API is structured it does not seem possible to obtain other properties using the "s" query parameter. What you could is make two requests. The first using the "s" query parameter, take the `imdbID` and make another request using the "i" query parameter. I know it is not optimal but it's something.